# flot stackpercent setdata bug

Tags: javascript, flot

I'm trying to update a flot graph using the stackpercent plugin. I wish to include the ability for users to turn legend items on and off, the problem is the chart isn't redrawn properly. The maths for determining % is ignored when using the draw() function as a result the graph doesn't look correct.

This is a [Documented bug](https://github.com/skeleton9/flot.stackpercent/issues/8). However, i don't see it being fixed anytime soon.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to call `setupGrid()` before `draw()`? And if nothing else works, you can always override the old plot.

Comment: setupGrid() does not work. Good idea though, setupGrid() does seem to fix most of the bugs I've encountered with flot. I should have thought to try it.